# Chilis that taste like habanero

Tags: substitutions

I like the fruity taste of habanero a lot (the red ones if that matters). But I usually get stomach pains after eating them (not that it stops me). Are there any chilis that taste similar to habanero but burns less/are easier on the stomach/have less scoville rating?

Comment: Manzanos are one of the other big fruity peppers, but they're only a little milder than habaneros, I'm guessing not enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the excellent book [Grow For Flavour](http://www.jameswong.co.uk/grow-for-flavour/4588092106) there is actually a chilli called the [Trinidad Perfume](https://www.kingsseeds.com/Products/Vegetables/Pepper/Pepper-Trinidad-Perfume) which is specifically cultivated to have the same flavour profile as a Habanero without the heat.

> If you love the tangy, fruitiness of habanero (Scotch bonnet) peppers but can't handle heat, I have some news for you. **Trinidad Perfume's** golden fruits have traded gut-wrenching fire for an incredibly flavourful, aromatic citrusiness [sic]. Being sweet and with barely any capsaicin, this is the ultimate chilli-hater's chilli.

<sub>p190. Grow for Flavour, James Wong. 2015 Mitchell Beazley</sub>

As to where one might find them - I suppose that mainly depends on your physical location. To be honest, I haven't seen them for sale around here (London).

Googling does provide a rather large number of options to buy seeds and even grown plants.

Comment: Wow.  I had never heard of that variety ... and it reminds me of something -- if you're growing peppers, you want to keep sweet peppers away from the hot peppers.  Cross pollination will result in the sweet ones getting hotter, and the hot ones losing some of their heat.

Comment: In shopping for seeds, I also found there's a 'Habanada' (it's not the same shape, though.  It's closer to a stretched out Scotch Bonnet), and for jalapeños there are 'Fooled You Hybrid' and 'Tricked You Hybrid', and for Scotch Bonnet, there's Aji Cachucha (which might have some heat)

Comment: @Joe I guess more than one person has had the idea of breeding the spice out of hot chilli peppers...

Answer (score 7):

Allepo pepper has a fair bit of fruitiness, but it's typically only available dried in most areas, not fresh.  And I suspect it may be harder to get these days with the conflict in the area where it's grown.

What you can do, however, is change how you use habanero peppers.

Add them whole to recipes and remove them before serving.  As the capsaicin is mostly on the inside, you'll get some of the fruitness, without the full hit from the heat.  If you want a little more heat, stab it with a knife before adding it (but don't cut it open fully).

One of my former co-workers made groundnut soup this way, and it had great flavor without knocking people out.  (I think he had 3 or 4 in there; I don't know if they were punctured or not)

Comment: And now that I think about it ... I wonder how the fruitiness vs. heat would be if you just *barely* scored the skin so you didn't actually cut all the way through to the internal cavity.  I might have to try to that on something where the flavor would stand out well.

Answer (score 1):

You can come down in hot but habanero does have a distinctive taste.

A trick is to remove the seeds as that is where most of hot is.

Substitute in some serrano or cayenne or ??